# How to map different values to single primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building an app that deals with restaurants and I'm trying to store all the food items they have in an SQL server, with the restaurant as a primary key. I was wondering how I could map all the menu items to that single primary key. Is that possible using SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your batcode, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes. It is possible using SQL.

Comment: You're asking us to rehearse the basics of Normalisation. That seems to me to be beyond the scope of this forum.